# semantic html - autocomplete results in combobox

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, semantic-markup

I have a `role="combobox"`, which opens up a `role="listbox"` when something is typed. The `listbox` has a list of items where the `<li>` are marked as `role="presentation"` and the children element as `role="option"`. The list items in this case have 2 bits of information, a primary text and a secondary text. should these list items simply be `div`s, or is there a better semantic element which can be used?

```
<input role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" ... />
<ul role="listbox">
  <li role="presentation">
    <div role="option">
      <div> primaryText </div>
      <div> sencondaryText </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a more semantic way to represent the primary and secondary text?
In a similar scenario, when search results are shown, I have seen each search result is an `<article>`, the title is either `<header>` or `<h1>`, and the secondary text is regular `<div>`. Does that structure make sense here?

Also, in some cases the results need to have a title, for example: "Results"
In that case I usually change the structure to:

```
<input role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" ... />
<div class="container">
  <div> Results </div>
  <ul role="listbox">
    <li role="presentation">
      <div role="option">
        <div> primaryText </div>
        <div> sencondaryText </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this case would it make sense to use a `<section>` like this

```
<input role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" ... />
  <section class="container">
    <header> Results </header>
    <ul role="listbox">
      <li role="presentation">
        <div role="option">
          <div> primaryText </div>
          <div> sencondaryText </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned here: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#presentation_role
Any children of the role="option" would behave as if they have role="presentation" applied to them, so doesn't matter whether they are divs or spans or heading tags, the semantics would be removed.

Comment: why are you using `role="presentation"`? Could you make one of the examples a bit more complete (a couple of `<li>`) showing what you are trying to achieve here or are all the `<li>` items the same?

Comment: Using role="presentation" so that assistive technology does not read it as list item but instead only read the div as "option". For an example, assume the autocomplete results are like Google maps, name of city is the primary text, and other details about the state/country is the secondary text.

Comment: More precisely, role=presentation because the ul is assigned a role, and so the li's should not be read by assistive technology as list items. I guess we could have role="option" on the li as well

Answer (score 1):

> should these list items simply be divs, or is there a better semantic element which can be used?

`<li>` is certainly one of the best fit for the items of your list box, except if individual results are quite long (see below) with your third question.

> Is there a more semantic way to represent the primary and secondary text?

As far as I know, no. You may use `<dl>, <dt>, <dd>` instead of `<ul>, <li>`.
Both are correct solutions, none is better than the other, between the two.

> In a similar scenario, when search results are shown, I have seen each search result is an `<article>`, the title is either `<header>` or `<h1>`, and the secondary
>   text is regular `<div>`. Does that structure make sense here?

It depends on how the results are going to be navigated.

If you are in the context of a form and if the results are navigated through by using arrow keys, which is the case for a typical combobox, the construction with `<article>` and headings is much less appropriate.

If you enter something to search, and then go out of the form to read the results, then `<article>` and headings is the best option, much better than simple `<ul> <li>`, because screen reader users can use keyboard shortcuts to navigate by heading or by section.

The length of the primary and secondary texts might be a criteria to help you decide which is the best option for your case.

For example, Google search results are used like the later, that's why they use a markup with headings.

> Also, in some cases the results need to have a title, for example: "Results" In that case I usually change the structure to:
>   ...
>   In this case would it make sense to use a like this

Yes, in this case it makes perfect sense.